# How to make the child form flickers?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a custom form that provides more options to customize the appearance of the form.I had a button in the parent form and by clicking the button i have shown another form by following code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CustomForm form = new CustomForm();
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I handled the On_Wm_NcActivate through the following code.Im thinking im not handling the On_Wm_NcActivate  correctly.

```
private void On_Wm_NcActivate(ref Message m)
{
    if (!this.IsMdiContainer)
        NativeMethods.LockWindowUpdate(this.Handle);
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    NativeMethods.LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
    if (Style != null)
    {
        var msg = new Message();
        msg.Msg = WindowMessages.WM_NCPAINT;
        msg.HWnd = m.HWnd;
        msg.WParam = (IntPtr)1;
        msg.LParam = (IntPtr)0;
        On_Wm_NcPaint(ref msg);
    }
}
```

I handled the On_Wm_NcPaint through the following code to customize the title bar and border and background of the overrided form.

```
private void On_Wm_NcPaint(ref Message m)
        {
            var rect = new NativePaint.RECT();
            NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(m.HWnd, ref rect);
            var deviceContext = NativeMethods.GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
            if (deviceContext != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var bufferDeviceContext = NativeMethods.CreateCompatibleDC(deviceContext);
                if (bufferDeviceContext != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    IntPtr bmp = NativeMethods.CreateCompatibleBitmap(deviceContext, rect.Width, rect.Height);

                    if (bmp != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        if (style == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        int borderThickness = 1;
                        var oldBmp = NativeMethods.SelectObject(bufferDeviceContext, bmp);
                        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(bufferDeviceContext))
                        {
                            //To clip the client area from painting based on the border thickness and title bar height.
                            var top = GetCaptionBarHeight() + (int)borderThickness + 5;
                            var left = (int)borderThickness;
                            var right = rect.Width - (int)borderThickness;
                            var bottom = rect.Height - (int)borderThickness;
                            if (FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
                                DrawFrame(graphics, rect);

                            if (FormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.None)
                            {
                                top = 0;
                                left = 0;
                                right = Width;
                                bottom = Height;
                            }

                            //Clip the client region from the window rectangle.
                            if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
                                NativeMethods.ExcludeClipRect(deviceContext, left + 1, top, right - 1, bottom - 1);

                            NativeMethods.BitBlt(deviceContext, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height, bufferDeviceContext, 0, 0, WindowMessages.SRCCOPY);
                            NativeMethods.SelectObject(bufferDeviceContext, oldBmp);
                            NativeMethods.DeleteObject(bmp);
                            NativeMethods.DeleteObject(oldBmp);
                            NativeMethods.DeleteDC(deviceContext);
                            NativeMethods.DeleteObject(bufferDeviceContext);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The Issue is while im clicking the parentform the child form is not flickers.
I dont know how to solve this issue.Can any one please give the solution for this issue.

Note: Icon in the taskbar flickers but the custom form is not flickering

Comment: Consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei,Im thinking i made the corrections as you said,I have found that Im not handling the On_Wm_NcActivate correctly.Im thinking i have missed something while handling.

Comment: This is a very strange question. Why are you using MFC message maps names for the methods? Are you *converting* an old project? Can't you just use [FlashWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex) to make your Form *flash*? Is it that what you mean with *flicker*?

Comment: Actually i have handled the messages by override the wndproc(ref message m),Im just customize the msdn form by override the wndproc() method.Sorry i dont have idea about the FlashWindowEx.While we use the showdailog() to show the Form and if you click in the parent window of the form with mouse the child form will not allow and the child form flickers.I want that flickering...

Comment: [Using FlashWindowEx](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FlashWindowEx)

Comment: Beware that the OP has written a message handler for WM_NCPAINT, but refuses to share that code.  Most obvious mistake he made is that what he paints is not based on whether or not the window is activated so always displays with the same colors.

Comment: Hi Hans Passant I havegiven the code of the WM_NCPAINT,As you said i have not paints based on the active window or not just i used the same color.

Comment: Hi HansPassant,thanks for your valuable suggestion i have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting clearly,

But you can do the Master, Child form using [MDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications) (Multiple Document Interface)

Comment: Hi Elango S,Actually the problem is i shown my custom form by CustomForm.ShowDailog().while clicking the parent form, my custom form should flickers...But my custom form is not flickering.In Mdsn form the flickering occurs.And it is not the mdiform.I have editted the code please refer the sample code.